# GPG key: No secret key

Tags: encryption, gnupg

My OS went bonkers and I had to fully reinstall. This means I did not have the chance to export the current key I had and import it on the new installation.

I generated the key locally, pushed it and I've had a bunch of people sign it.

I am getting the error though:

```
Karls-MBP:ne karl$ pass app_secret
gpg: public key decryption failed: No secret key
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

We are using pass to store secrets. I have no idea how to fix this? How do I debug this error message?

Comment: Does `gpg -K` return `sec`?

Comment: @JW0914 Indeed it does! `sec   rsa4096 2022-05-18 [SC]`

Comment: That verifies the secret key is there then, so it implies the wrong key may have been provided for trust signing _(double check the last eight characters in the key's hash, verifying it matches the hash of the key(s) returned via `gpg -K`, and if using a subkey, ensure its apart of the main key)_. I've also never used `pass`, but the `gpg` error implies there's a key mismatch between what was provided for signing and what exists with the private key(s) returned by `gpg -K`.

Comment: _(Cont'd...)_ For future reference, you may wish to do what I do: Since I store my keys on a hardware key, prior to `keytocard` I manually export the main  _and_ each individual subkey separately with their corresponding private keys, encrypted with a 20+ char passphrase containing at least two each of lowercase, uppercase, symbols, and numbers _(provided this specific passphrase policy is adhered to, it's safe to store it in the cloud)_. This ensures I have an encrypted hardcopy backup if the hardware key is forced to erase for security by three bad pin attempts or if the key becomes damaged.

Comment: @JW0914 Thanks for the information bombs dude!

Answer (score 2):

If you have lost the private key and you don't have a backup,
then there is nothing you can do about the old key-pair.

You should generate a new pair of keys and
let anyone who uses the old key know that you have a new one.

For the next time, ensure you have backups.

Comment: I see, that does make sense. Regarding letting people know who uses the old one, how does one figure that out? I have a copy of the old key ID, is there a way to figure out who has signed the old key?

Comment: If you have uploaded the key, you need to revoke it. If you have used it for private email, once you get an email you can't decode, then you have found one such user.